# JavaScript if / else statement not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

Can anyone check this part of code please? I think there's an syntax problem in it but I can't figure out what it is. I'm more like a designer so I have very basic javascript skills

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var lightstand = 0;

    $('.light').on('click', function() {
        if(lightstand == 0) {
            $('.card').css('background-image','url(img/SOCMUT_eindejaarskaartje_10-2016_HR_BLANCO.jpg)');
            $('#canvas').css('opacity','1');
            var lightstand = 1;
        } else if (lightstand == 1) {
            $('.card').css('background-image','url(img/SOCMUT_eindejaarskaartje_10-2016_HR_BLANCO12.jpg)');
            $('#canvas').css('opacity','0');
            var lightstand = 0;
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you think there's a syntax problem?  Is there some *actual indication* of an error?

Comment: You *think* there's a syntax problem with it?  What problem are you actually experiencing?

Comment: Syntactically the code seems fine, though re-declaring that same variable in the `if` and `else` blocks doesn't seem logically correct.  I suspect you want to set the value of the existing variable, not declare a new one.

Comment: In all seriousness, no. The syntax looks fine.. You should check to see if there are any errors and post them with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in resetting `lightstand`. by putting `var` in front of it inside thew click event handler, you are creating a new `lightstand` variable in the that function's scope. Remove `var` there and JavaScript will move up the scope chain to find the outer lightstand and set it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var lightstand = 0; //KEEP VAR HERE

   $('.light').on('click', function() {
       if(lightstand == 0) {
           $('.card').css('background-image','url(img/SOCMUT_eindejaarskaartje_10-2016_HR_BLANCO.jpg)');
           $('#canvas').css('opacity','1');
           lightstand = 1; //REMOVE VAR FROM HERE
       } else if (lightstand == 1) {
           $('.card').css('background-image','url(img/SOCMUT_eindejaarskaartje_10-2016_HR_BLANCO12.jpg)');
           $('#canvas').css('opacity','0');
           lightstand = 0; //REMOVE VAR FROM HERE TOO!!
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fairly good run down on scope in JavaScript
http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're experiencing issues because you're declaring your variable `nightstand` multiple times.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ var lightstand = 0;
    var lightstand = 0;
    $('.light').on('click', function() {
        if(nightstand === 0) {
            $('.card').css('background-image','url(img/SOCMUT_eindejaarskaartje_10-2016_HR_BLANCO.jpg)');
            $('#canvas').css('opacity','1');
            lightstand = 1;
        } else if (lightstand == 1) {
            $('.card').css('background-image','url(img/SOCMUT_eindejaarskaartje_10-2016_HR_BLANCO12.jpg)');
            $('#canvas').css('opacity','0');
            lightstand = 0;
            }
    }); 
});
```

---

Edit:

Just to further elaborate on what you can do in the future:
- If you think an if/else statement is not behaving correctly, test it with

```
alert('hello from IF'); 
alert('hello from ELSE');
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
console.log('text');
console.log(variable);
```

If you think there's something wrong with your syntax, check if using jshint.com

Comment: This does the trick Robert thanks. Can you explain what you changed? What's the difference between === and ==?

Comment: `===` checks to see if they are the same type and equal; `==` checks to see if they are logically the same. So 0==false, but 0!===false

Comment: But the bigger change was not re-declaring `int lightstand` in your if-else block.

Comment: @MDC have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript but note that this had nothing to do with the solution :)

Comment: == will convert both sides to a similar type (usually a number, or a string) before checking for sameness. === will look at value type and value in its evaluation. != and !== work similarly.